# Wrapping text in crystal so that it does not add extra row in excel

Tags: excel, crystal-reports-export

I have a field in crystal reports that has a lot of text. For that I went into Format editor and allowed wrapping of text for that field. Now when I export my report in pdf, it looks fine, but when I export it to excel it adds an extra row below a record that has more text in that field. How can I make it so that it does not add a extra row, but wraps the text in single cell only.

Comment: I haven't worked with crytal reports at all, but I will caution you that excel will generally not output more than 255 characters into a cell programtically. The extra rows are likely an artifact of this excel limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with extra rows and columns in my Crystal Reports exports.  From what I can tell from my searching that it is caused by fields not lining up or being different sizes.  You might be able to fix your issue by making all your fields in the row larger so they are the same height as the field with the large amount of text.

See this page:
[Blank columns appear when exporting to Excel.](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/reporting-services/416-blank-columns-issue-when-exporting-to-excel-data-only-from-crystal-reports.html)